# Android Studio: Can't run tutorial app because of HAXM

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I start to learn Android Development using Android Studio, so when I apply what is in the Run app page (android 5.0): https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html I get

```
C:\Users\?!?!\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed     full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I searched here and I found that I should install: Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer), I download it but the problem is that my CPU does not support intel Virtualization Technology. so how can I run apps without it. Please Help I'm STACK. thanks

Comment: You got an answer but ARM version is slower than x86 version. I recommend Genymotion, it's really fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and use the ARM version of the emulator image.